# Is there a way to paste a date into a Chrome date field?

Tags: google-chrome, copy-paste, date-time, forms, html5

When filling in a form in Chrome, HTML5 forms have a nifty date field nowadays which Chrome renders a rather helpful date picker.

This is nice unless you have loads of forms to fill in.

I'd like to to paste in a date but I can't find a way to paste a date into the field in Chrome.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I do this?

Comment: I use autohotkey scripting to automate things. It is very easy to learn  and forums are very helpful. Www.Autohotkey.Com

Comment: Pasting in a date using autohotkey is really easy. It's definitely worth a play around with. You'll find lots of other uses. Like shortcuts to type in email. And much more

Comment: Looks great - I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue but also needed to be able to paste to another date field. I did something similar to the above but made it obvious to the user that the full date is being copied.

My use case also included the need to copy from and paste to datetime-local type fields.

https://jsfiddle.net/h444uL45/23/

```
var control_pressed = false;

function changeInputType(oldObject, oType) {
  var newObject = document.createElement("input");
  newObject.type = oType;
  if(oldObject.size) {newObject.size = oldObject.size;}
  if(oldObject.value) {newObject.value = oldObject.value;}
  if(oldObject.name) {newObject.name = oldObject.name;}
  if(oldObject.id) {newObject.id = oldObject.id;}
  if(oldObject.className) {newObject.className = oldObject.className;}
  oldObject.parentNode.replaceChild(newObject,oldObject);
  newObject.select();
  return newObject;
}

function swapToText(date_type) {
    $('input[type="'+date_type+'"]').on("keydown", function(event) {
    if ((event.keyCode == 17) && (control_pressed != true)) {
      $(this).addClass("revert_date_to_text");
      changeInputType(this, "text");
      swapToDate(date_type);
      control_pressed = true;
    }
  })
}

function swapToDate(date_type) {
  $(".revert_date_to_text").on("keyup", function(event) {
    if ((event.keyCode == 17) && (control_pressed != false)) {
      $(this).removeClass("revert_date_to_text");
      if (date_type == 'datetime-local') {
        $(this).val($.format.date($(this).val().replace(/\//g,"-").replace("T"," ")+':00.000', "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm"));
      } else {
        $(this).val($.format.date($(this).val().replace(/\//g,"-"), "yyyy-MM-dd"));
      }
      changeInputType(this, date_type);
      swapToText(date_type);
      control_pressed = false;
    }
  })
}

$(function() {
  $.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-dateFormat/1.0/jquery.dateFormat.min.js');
  swapToText('date');
  swapToText('datetime-local');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotKey seems to be the way to go so thanks to KickAss for the pointer in the comments.

Not as *quite* easy as a <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> but it does work and opens up other macro-ing fun!

Comment: @JohnReid: Whilst I disagree with the answer being flagged as a comment, it may helpful if you add some more detail about the script, otherwise it may be deleted automatically.

Comment: @James Ah, fair enough - I'll update it shorty.